# Deserialize JSON with empty string key

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin, datacontract

These are the data contract class and attributes below.

```
public partial class ValidationErrors
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Message;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public ModelState ModelState;
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class ModelState
{   
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string[] empty;
}
```

This is the JSON code where I'm getting the issue and is after the "ModelState" where no field name is given.

How do I create data Contract classes to reflect the JSON below?

```
 {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Some messege is being displayed"]}}
```

**EDIT** Code to proccess deserialization:

```
Stream res= await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
object result= ModelStateSerializer.ReadObject(res);
```

Comment: `class ModelState: Dictionary<string, List<string>> { }`

Comment: Any particular reason you HAVE to use data contracts

Comment: @Nkosi building xamarin app cross server and cannot use web based stuff

Comment: And what about Json.Net?

Comment: @Nkosi Ive changed the class to   
  
' [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public class ModelState : Dictionary<string, List<string>> { }'

Comment: Plus Data members should be properties and not fields.

Comment: ive changed to : [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public ModelState modelState  { get; set; }

Comment: @Nkosi I havent really looked into Json.net i wasnt keen on installing  3rd party so just stuck with whatever was native to microsoft. but may switch as this is giving me problems. havent worked in this project in a while

Comment: @Nkosi "modelState" object is till null when debugging

Comment: Hold on drafting up an example.

Comment: Take a look at the following example that uses Json.Net https://dotnetfiddle.net/uLDLTm The generated JSON matches what was described in your question.

Comment: How does this code know it is parsing JSON? `System.Runtime.Serialization` is the builtin serializer, not for JSON, AFAIK

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the example. I would like to see if there is a solution with data contract  before switching over to netwon

Comment: @cricket_007  I will add it as an edit

Comment: You might want to look at https://blog.udemy.com/json-serializer-c-sharp/

Comment: @cricket_007 It is able to deserialize the "message" attribute/field

Comment: @cricket_007 you article doesnt actually deal with the issue please re-read question

Comment: I did read it. Did you see the section on deserialization?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes Please see the edited version of this question where i provide code for deserialization

Comment: I don't see the edited code that uses a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, as mentioned

Comment: @cricket_007  should be clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Using the following class structure

```
public partial class ValidationErrors {
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ModelState ModelState { get; set; }
}

public partial class ModelState : Dictionary<string, List<string>> {

}
```

The following example demonstrates how to use *Json.Net* to generate the desired JSON described in the original question.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var errors = new ValidationErrors {
        Message = "The request is invalid.",
        ModelState = new ModelState {
            { "", new List<string>(){"Some messege is being displayed"} }   
        }
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

*Output:*

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Some messege is being displayed"]}}
```

The output JSON is able to be deserialized to the same class structure used in the serialization.

The following example reads the content of a response and converts it to the desired type.

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var errors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValidationErrors>(json);
var message = errors.Message;
var modelState = errors.ModelState;
var details = modelState[""].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Im actually trying to deserialize.

Comment: Can't you just do `public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ModelState {get; set;}`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you can do that as well. It will work the same. The OP already had a class structure so I decided to include the class.

Comment: @Nkosi I will consider using Json.net at last resort if i cannot find a solution with data contract. behold my ignorance.

Comment: @MarkEvans the choice is yours. I just provided you with an option. Hope it helps. Happy coding.